# Why is .NET Framework 4.5.2 showing as an optional update?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-update

On one of my Windows 2008 R2 servers the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 shows in the list of optional updates. However, when I click on it the description states it is a recommended update. On my other Windows 2008 R2 server it appeared in the list of important Updates. Anybody know why it appears in the list of optional updates on this server? Does this indicate that I need to manually install it and perform some additional actions? I already have .NET Framework 4.5.1 installed.

[image: Windows Update Screenshot]

And here is a screenshot from another server showing the .NET Framework 4.5.2 in the Important list:

[image]

Comment: Do both servers have the same software?  I wonder if one system has a dependency on the framework.

Comment: Both servers have the same software. One server is a standby for the other so they are very similar.